# Video error in titanium for AWS signed URLs

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, titanium, appcelerator

I have a video playing in titanium on iOS.

The video is coming from Amazon Cloudfront and it is a signed URL. It loads up just fine. I have the expiry set to 30 seconds for debug purposes for now.

After 30 seconds, I seek forward and I get a statement in the console stating:

`Took background task assertion (9) for playback stall`

That message is being presented because the MP4 that was playing, is now expired and I must generate a new signed url.

The problem is I cannot find a video event for this behavior. I tried doing a

`vidPlayer.addEventListener('error', function(){...});` but this event never fires.

Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: I figured it out. You want to use the `loadstate` event and listen for `event.loadState == 5`

Comment: I should also note, loadstate doesn't seem to work in android.